# select from database where id in Field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Database for news i use multi cats in each news so i have a filed in database called cats and i insert data inside it like that `1,5,8,2` this data is the cats id.

And i use this code to select cats from database

```
$select_newscats = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news_cats where show_home = '1' and  kind = 1 or kind = 2 order by ord_show asc");

while ($rows_newscats = $select_newscats->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){

    $id_newscats          = $rows_newscats ['id'];
    $title_newscats       = $rows_newscats ['title'];
    $ord_show_newscats    = $rows_newscats ['ord_show'];
    $icon_newscats        = $rows_newscats ['icon'];
    $kind_newscats        = $rows_newscats ['kind'];
    $description_newscats = $rows_newscats ['description'];

}
```

i want to select news from database where this  `$id_newscats` inside cats filed in news table so i traied this code to get news data

```
$select_newscats = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news_cats where show_home = '1' and  kind = 1 or kind = 2 order by ord_show asc");

while ($rows_newscats = $select_newscats->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){

    $id_newscats          = $rows_newscats ['id'];
    $title_newscats       = $rows_newscats ['title'];
    $ord_show_newscats    = $rows_newscats ['ord_show'];
    $icon_newscats        = $rows_newscats ['icon'];
    $kind_newscats        = $rows_newscats ['kind'];
    $description_newscats = $rows_newscats ['description'];


    $select_news = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news where $id_newscats  IN (cats)");
    while ($rows_news = $select_news->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){

        $id_new          = $rows_news ['id'];
        $title_news       = $rows_news ['title'];

        echo "<div>{$title_news}</div>";
    }
}
```

but i have a problem with this code it select only first one for example if i have this cats id's `5,2,7` it gives me only news from this id `5` and ignore `2,7` so how can i fix that and select all news where this id `$id_newscats` in cats Field Thanks.

Comment: You should fix your data structure to have a proper junction table rather than storing ids in a row.  The reasons why a junction table is better are too long to explain in a comment.

Comment: Remove this line: `$rows_news   = $select_news->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC);` It's not necessary as you are setting value to `$rows_news` within the `while()` loop already.

Comment: @Marcus i removed it but this is not the problem

Comment: I know. Your problem appears to be with the second query. You're assuming `$id_newscats` will hold value `5, 2, 7`, correct? Or something of the like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got this

change this

```
$select_news = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news where $id_newscats  IN (cats)");
```

into this

```
$select_news = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news where FIND_IN_SET('$id_newscats', cats) ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is both  syntax(1) and Logical(2) error.

1. `SELECT * FROM news where $id_newscats IN (cats)` is wrong .

    This is the correct syntax.
     `$select_news =
   $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news where cats IN ($id_newscats)")`
2. Use paranthesis in your Query.

   `SELECT * FROM news_cats where show_home = '1' and  (kind = 1 or kind = order by ord_show asc"`

Comment: but the id_newscats inside cats not cats in id_newscats

Answer (score 0):

You have your `IN` query in the wrong order.

```
$select_news = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news where cats IN ($id_newscats)")
```

Comment: but the id_newscats inside cats not cats in id_newscats

Comment: This can't be fixed that easily, since your database structure should have a mapping between the `news` table and the `news_cats` table. So you get all entries from that mapping table for a specified category first and then query for the news ids from that mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You are not building an IN list in the outer while loop! You get ONE row and then in the inner loop you only have ONE id to search with so there is no need for the `IN` syntax. **Which is wrong anyway**

Your outer query also look Wrong, I think you need some brackets round the OR.

```
$select_newscats = $mysqli->query("SELECT * 
                                   FROM news_cats 
                                   WHERE show_home = '1' 
                                    and  ( kind = 1 or kind = 2 ) 
                                   ORDER BY ord_show asc");

while ($rows_newscats = $select_newscats->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){

    $id_newscats          = $rows_newscats ['id'];
    $title_newscats       = $rows_newscats ['title'];
    $ord_show_newscats    = $rows_newscats ['ord_show'];
    $icon_newscats        = $rows_newscats ['icon'];
    $kind_newscats        = $rows_newscats ['kind'];
    $description_newscats = $rows_newscats ['description'];

    // amended query, you only have one $id_newscats
    //  each time round this outer loop
    $select_news = $mysqli->query("SELECT * 
                                   FROM news 
                                   WHERE id = $id_newscats");

    while ($rows_news = $select_news->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){

        $id_new          = $rows_news ['id'];
        $title_news       = $rows_news ['title'];

        // no need for {} round scalar variables
        //echo "<div>{$title_news}</div>";
        echo "<div>$title_news</div>";

        // or you could just dothis and dont bother 
        // creating an unecessary scalar variable
        //echo "<div>{$rows_news['title']}</div>";
    }
}
```